# Tensorflow Dataset API restore Iterator after completing one epoch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have 190 features and labels,My batch size is  20 but after 9 iterations `tf.reshape` is returning exception **Input to reshape is a tensor with 21 values,but the requested shape has 60** and i know it is due to `Iterator.get_next()`.How do i restore my Iterator so that it will again start serving batches from the beginning?

Comment: Can you just drop the last batch that is smaller than others? If so, you can use [`tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder `](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder).

Comment: Remaining batch is important to me,I don's think so i can do that.But thanks i'll just create by own batching code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to restart a [`tf.data.Iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Iterator) from the beginning of its `Dataset`, consider using an **initializable** iterator, which has an operation you can run to re-initialize the iterator:

```
dataset = ...  # A `tf.data.Dataset` instance.
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

train_op = ...  # Something that depends on `next_element`.

for _ in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  # Initialize the iterator at the beginning of `dataset`.
  sess.run(iterator.initializer)

  # Loop over the examples in `iterator`, running `train_op`.
  try:
    while True:
      sess.run(train_op)

  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:  # Thrown at the end of the epoch.
    pass

  # Perform any per-epoch computations here.
```

For more details on the different kinds of `Iterator`, see [the `tf.data` programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator).

Comment: Couldn't find make_initializable_iterator in the 2.x documentation. Was it removed or did I miss it?