# How to do a pairwise iteration over two unequal-length tf.datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator

I work with two datasets of unequal length.

My goal is to take for every element in datasetA an element from the other datasetB. I tried `.take(1)` (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518079/retrieving-the-next-element-from-tf-data-dataset-in-tensorflow-2-0-beta)) to get a single element from datasetB, but repeatedly calling `.take(1)` does not advance the internal count of the dataset, i.e., it always returns the same element; but I want to get a new element every time.

I can iterate over one dataset using `for element in datasetA:`, and then consume the second dataset inside as `elementB = iterB.get_next()`. This throws errors when `iterB` is consumed.

This is the full toy code I am working with:

```
datasetA = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 6])
datasetB = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([11, 22, 33, 44])

iterB = iter(datasetB)
epochs = 5

for epoch in range(epochs):
  print(f"Epoch {epoch}")
  for element in datasetA:
    print(element)
    elementB = iterB.get_next()
    print(elementB)
```

I then proceeded to:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
  print(f"Epoch {epoch}")
  for element in datasetA:
    print(element)
    elementB = iterB.get_next_as_optional()
    if not elementB.has_value():
      iterB = iter(datasetB)
      elementB = iterB.get_next_as_optional()

    print(elementB.get_value())
```

Which works, but it's hacky to reinitialize the iterator for `datasetB`.

What I further found is this [for old TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216946/tensorflow-dataset-api-restore-iterator-after-completing-one-epoch), which uses a TF operation to re-initialize the iterator, which is no longer available.
This is also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711103/difference-between-tf-data-dataset-repeat-vs-iterator-initializer), which was helpful but did no lead me to a TF2.+ solution.

What I am looking for is an elegant way to get pairwise elements from `datasetA` and `datasetB`, where datasetB is (automatically) repeated when it's consumed.

What I do not need is to iterate over a combined dataset, unless the shorter dataset gets "filled" to the longer one by being repeated, and I can then sample pairs (A, B) with A from datasetA and B from datasetB.

TL;DR:
Want pairwise iteration over two datasets of unequal lengths, restart shorter dataset when consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all possible pairs of samples from two datasets, one can use the following `generator`:

```
    # assuming that dataset_A and dataset_B are defined globally
    def generator():
        for sample_A in dataset_A:
            for sample_B in dataset_B:
                yield (sample_A, sample_B)
```

To get only pairs of samples that are at the same positions in the datasets (same index), there is a standard `zip` method:

```
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(dataset_A, dataset_B)
```

Such generator stops when one of the datasets is depleted.

If the goal is to get pair-wise samples for all samples from `dataset_A`, but `dataset_B` is smaller, one can infinitely repeat the second dataset,

```
     dataset_B = dataset_B.repeat()
```

and then `zip` the two datasets.

Comment: This goes in the direction, but will go for every sample from datasetA over the complete datasetB. My intent is to iterate them simultaneously, so that when I take the second sample from datasetA I also take the second sample from datasetB.

Comment: Edited the answer to get the desired dataset.

Comment: While this does not fully answer my question it seems to be the closest that I can currently get! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to "restart" `dataset_B` when it is depleted, but not all elements from `dataset_A` were used? If this is the goal, then, before zipping, call `dataset_B = dataset_B.repeat()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this coding language but here is what you should be doing.

```
datasetA = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 6]);
datasetB = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([11, 22, 33, 44]);
set i=0,j=0;
get lengths of both alength and blength;
for(i=0;i<alength;i++){
 print(datasetA[i]);
 print(datasetB[j]);
 if(j<blength-1)
   j++;
 else
  j=0;  
 }
```